# Контекстные селеторы относительно родителя:active не работают в некоторых браузерах

Tags: html, css

Элементарный код:

```
<a href="#">
    <span>test</span>
<a>
```

Элементарный селектор с active:

```
a:hover {color: black;}
a:active span { color: white; }
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BMHUz/114/)

Никакой реакции на код второго селектора в последних версиях Оперы и IE. Подскажите, пожалуйста, это я не прав или браузер? :). Как можно попробовать обойти?

**UPD:** более показательный вариант: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BMHUz/116/)

Comment: Наверно вы не правы. Первый раз такой селектор вижу:)

Comment: Хм, ну тормозилла и вебкиты на моей стороне :). Так то псевдокласс :active и контекстные селекторы давным давно всеми браузерами должны пониматься.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело в том, что опера и хром по разному понимают клик по объекту, в Вашем случае задан стиль для ссылки в то время как Вы кликаете по `span`. на [примере](http://jsfiddle.net/_FLK/HrNLd/2/) думаю будет понятней.

Comment: ухххх ... Спасибо :)